# iOS accessing properties from a C function

Tags: ios, xcode, class, properties

.mm file:
[image]

.h file:

[image]

is it possible to create an instance of my iBeaconScanner class and store it in *ibeaconScanner property? I need to keep a strong reference to ibeaconScanner property and needs to be called from a C function.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have one `iBeaconScanner`, you can do that with a `static` variable

```
static iBeaconScanner *globalScanner = nil;
@implementation iBeaconScannerPlugin
-(id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (globalScanner == nil) {
        globalScanner = [iBeaconScanner new];
    }
    _ibeaconScanner = globalScanner;
    return self;
}
@end

extern "C" 
{
    void _initScanner() {
         if (globalScanner == nil) {
              globalScanner = [iBeaconScanner new];
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks Sahara for your answer, sadly Xcode crashes, as if it gets into an endless loop..

Comment: not sure, cause it doesn't break at a line, I have to force quite Xcode.
What I'm actually trying here is to generate a local notification when my ibeacon is detected, the reason I'm using C is because this is a plugin for Unity3D and thats the only way I can access iOS codes from inside the Unity app.

Comment: Did you add Exception break point? If yes, can you look at other thread to see what happen?